# How can I say "why are you making a duck face" in Russian?

Tags: phrase

How can I say "why are you making a duck face" in Russian?

Comment: What does it mean? If you tell me, I will tell you how to say it in Russian.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=duck+face&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS426US426&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Mj1GUfvnM6e32wXItYHICA&ved=0CFcQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=880

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The literal translation is “Зачем ты выпячиваешь губы?” You can also say “Зачем ты гримасничаешь?”

Comment: Why is the down vote?

Comment: +1, this is much more natural-sounding than the other answers

Comment: +1 "Выпячивать губы" looks to me the closest definition in Russian to the phenomenon shown on google images for "duckface". "Губки трубочкой" does not exactly fit because in duckface it is a combination of protruded lips AND some kind of smile. In other words lips are forward, but not round but flat. "Губки бантиком" maybe is better fit than "трубочкой" but I think it is mostly used for describing a face of a person (child) offended by something and about to cry.

Answer (score 4):

That sentence makes me smile. Sure enough, to its credit, Urban Dictionary, being an open resource, at the same time would unlikely be considered the most trustworthy one on the web in this respect, and yet, here is an entry I like:"A facial expression utilized by attention-seeking teenage girls in which they push their lips outward and upward to give the appearance of large, pouty lips.
Amanda Fuchs makes a duckface in all of her profile pictures."

Some coquetry given, I would suggest something like Милая, к чему такое"поцелуйное"личико? or Ты уверена, что твоя утиная гримаска здесь уместна?

Internet yields another sample:"...сбегала к зеркалу, скроила утиную морду - реально кажется. что суперсекси..." which indicates that the English authentic(?), not sure about its etymology, phrase has been successfully infiltrating the Russian everyday speech).

Answer (score 3):

*why are you making a duck face?*

- Зачем ты делаешь лицо «уточкой»?
- Зачем ты делаешь губы «уточкой»?

*making a duck face* - сделать/показать «уточку» (short form)

Comment: _Делать "дакфейс"_ can also be used.

Comment: @YellowSky чё ты дакфейсишь тут!

Answer (score 2):

зачем делать губки бантиком???

Comment: Please refrain from reposting information already present in other answers.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to when you say it's already been presented. I don't see any earlier answer/response mentioning "бантик". Please explain yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Young people mostly use a word "дакфейс" (read exactly like englich 'duck face' ), specially when facing a phenomenon of a young woman wearing this facial expression on a photo. A verb would be "сделать дакфейс" (perfect form), and here is another common example:

> > На новом фото Катя опять с дакфейсом

(Katya makes a duck face on her photo again)

Other examples in this thread feel a bit odd to me. They are correct indeed but suit older people or some official speech better (f.e. journal, book), however, the duck face phenomenon is clearly out of the list of topics discussed in journals or between politics.

Answer (score 0):

Почему ты придуриваешься уткой?

Comment: This is not correct at all.  It doesn't convey the same meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

"Хватит дуться" or "Чего ты дуешься?". It is slang.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage! We prefer long, elaborate answers. You could, for example, explain, what exactly the translation mean and say whether they are used in exactly the same situations and the English phrase. For more information on how to make a good answer, please read ["How to answer"](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: My gut says, the sitational uses are different for the OP question and suggested translation. I'd say that `дуться` is `pout`.

Answer (score 0):

the old form of duckface in russian is "губошлёп". you can say "зачем ты прикидываешься губошлёпом?". or if you talk this to women "почему ты надуваешь губки?")